# Deploying with capistrano 3 and whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my app with `whenever` gem using `capistrano 3`.

I added: `require "whenever/capistrano"` to Capfile, and:

`set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }`
to config/deploy.rb.

When I deploy it I get an error:

```
01 bundler: failed to load command: whenever (/home/deploy/www/laptophits/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/whenever)

NameError: undefined local variable or method `extract' for #<Whenever::JobList:0x00000002edf6c8>
      config/schedule.rb:9:in `block in initialize'
```

When I ssh to production machine and try to run whenever manually with: `/home/deploy/www/laptophits/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/whenever`

I get error:

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem whenever (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key error is in

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `extract' for #<Whenever::JobList:0x00000002edf6c8>
  config/schedule.rb:9:in `block in initialize'
```

There's likely a code bug on line 9 of `config/schedule.rb`. Probably using the method `extract` which doesn't exist on the object or in the context in which you are using it.

Comment: I forgot quotes in rake task name.